# Accepting Terms and Conditions with Python and Mechanize

Tags: python, post, mechanize

I'm using Python and Mechanize to search a database and return results. I'm having a problem getting through the Terms and Conditions page to access the actual database search page.

I've tried using Mechanize to manipulate the Agree button on the page but I am getting this response.

```
<Form1 POST http://www.wataugacounty.org/ias/Search/Disclaimer2.aspx?FromUrl=..%
 2fsearch%2fcommonsearch.aspx%3fmode%3dparid application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <HiddenControl(__EVENTTARGET=)>
  <HiddenControl(__EVENTARGUMENT=)>
  <HiddenControl(__VIEWSTATE=/wEPDwUKLTk3MzgyMzUzOQ8UKwACZGdkZARSom15z0v0QyobiaK
gUmCf0EcW)>
  <IgnoreControl(btDisagree=<None>)>
  <IgnoreControl(btAgree=<None>)>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 19, in <module>
    br["btAgree"] = 'True'
   File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\mechanize\_form.py", line 2784, in __setit
em__
raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: control 'btAgree' is ignored, hence read-only
```

I'm not sure if Mechanize is capable of processing the acceptance. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mechanize won't cut it because it doesn't evaluate Javascript code and you really need it because the input button triggers a Javascript function. Even if you try to use Mechanize to simply submit the form, you'll get the following message:

> The web site is unable to acknowledge your acceptance of the
>   disclaimer message.   This situation is typically caused when your web
>   browser is set to prevent the use of Javascript.  This site requires
>   that Javascript be enabled in your browser.  Javascript is a
>   programming language that allows us to provide you with a richer and
>   more enjoyable experience than would otherwise be the case.  This site
>   will not operate without Javascript.

You've got some alternatives though.

- [ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) is a headless webkit web client (and, as such, it'll run Javascript)
- [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)
- Also noteworthy (although not written in Python) is [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), another headless webkit client

Comment: can you please provide an short example of how to do it with Selenium. I tried:`term_form = driver.find_element_by_id("Form1")
term_form = driver.find_element_by_id("Form1").submit()``but it does not work. The website pops up but I still need to click the button for accepting terms and conditions

Comment: @hoangtran sorry, but you need to create a new question. This is 5 years old and I've since moved on. I haven't worked with Selenium for years.